# A (late) Simple Calculator

Tags: java, unit-testing, community-challenge, math-expression-eval

As I was looking through my past questions, I noticed my really old calculator question ([here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57134/simple-calculator-that-seems-inefficient) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57331/simple-calculator-revised)). Considering it looked like a huge mess, I decided to rewrite it. Coincidentally, the [April 2015 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/april-2015-community-challenge) was to implement a simple calculator. It might be a bit late, but here it is:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Calculator {

    private static final Pattern NUMBER_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

    public static double calculate(String equation) {
        return calculate(equation, Operation.getLastInPrecedence());
    }

    private static double calculate(String equation, Operation currentOp) {
        Operation nextOp = currentOp.getPreviousInPrecedence();
        if (NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(equation).matches()) {
            return Double.parseDouble(equation);
        }
        String[] equationParts = equation.split("\\s*"
                + Pattern.quote(Character.toString(currentOp.getSymbol()))
                + "\\s*");
        double result;
        if (nextOp == null) {
            // Last operation
            result = Math.pow(Integer
                    .parseInt(equationParts[equationParts.length - 2]), Integer
                    .parseInt(equationParts[equationParts.length - 1]));
            for (int i = equationParts.length - 3; i >= 0; i--) {
                result = Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(equationParts[i]), result);
            }
        } else {
            result = calculate(equationParts[0], nextOp);
            for (int i = 1; i < equationParts.length; i++) {
                result = currentOp.execute(result, calculate(equationParts[1],
                        nextOp));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}

class Operation {

    public static final Operation ADD = new Operation('+', 1);
    public static final Operation SUBTRACT = new Operation('-', 2);
    public static final Operation MULTIPLY = new Operation('*', 3);
    public static final Operation DIVIDE = new Operation('/', 4);

    public static final Operation POW = new Operation('^', 5);

    private static final Map<Integer, Operation> operations = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        operations.put(ADD.precedence, ADD);
        operations.put(SUBTRACT.precedence, SUBTRACT);
        operations.put(MULTIPLY.precedence, MULTIPLY);
        operations.put(DIVIDE.precedence, DIVIDE);
        operations.put(POW.precedence, POW);
    }

    private final char symbol;
    private final int precedence;

    private Operation(char symbol, int precedence) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.precedence = precedence;
    }

    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public int getPrecedence() {
        return precedence;
    }

    public double execute(double left, double right) {
        if (this == ADD) {
            return left + right;
        } else if (this == SUBTRACT) {
            return left - right;
        } else if (this == MULTIPLY) {
            return left * right;
        } else if (this == DIVIDE) {
            return left / right;
        } else if (this == POW) {
            return Math.pow(left, right);
        } else {
            // Not Possible
            throw new InternalError();
        }
    }

    public Operation getNextInPrecedence() {
        return operations.get(precedence - 1);
    }

    public Operation getPreviousInPrecedence() {
        return operations.get(precedence + 1);
    }

    public static Operation getFromPrecedence(int precedence) {
        return operations.get(precedence);
    }

    public static Operation getLastInPrecedence() {
        return ADD;
    }

    public static Operation getFirstInPrecedence() {
        return POW;
    }

}
```

The logic here is fairly simple:

- I have a recursive solution that goes through the operations, in reverse precedence. This way, the highest precedence operations are calculated first.
- The method will first check if the given equation is a number. If it is, it just returns the parsed number.
- If not, it continues executing. It will first split the equation into the parts that are separated by the current operation, and calculates them by recursively calling this method.
- If it is the last operation (i.e. `pow` or `^`), then it will perform a different method, going from right to left. Explanation will appear later in this post. Explanation:

In addition (or subtraction or multiplication or whatever), you go from left to right:

```
1 + 2 + 3
```

is essentially the same as:

$$1 + 2 + 3$$

but with `pow`, you have to go from right to left.

```
2 ^ 3 ^ 2
```

Is the same as:

$$2 ^ {3 ^ 2}$$

As long as you go from right to left. If you go from left to right though, it will result in:

$$(2 ^ 3) ^ 2$$

\$2 ^ {3 ^ 2}\$ is `512`, which does not equal \$(2 ^ 3) ^ 2\$ (`64`).

- Once all the operations are complete, it will either return the result, or throw an exception due to a over-complicated equation.

I also have tests:

```
class Test {

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        assertEquals(6.0, Calculator.calculate("3.5 + 2.5"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubtract() {
        assertEquals(1.0, Calculator.calculate("3.5 - 2.5"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiply() {
        assertEquals(8.75, Calculator.calculate("3.5 * 2.5"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testDivide() {
        assertEquals(1.4, Calculator.calculate("3.5 / 2.5"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPow() {
        assertEquals(9.0, Calculator.calculate("3 ^ 2"));
    }

}
```

Major concerns:

1. The code seems to be fixed for this specific problem. If I were to add another operation, the design has to be changed a lot. Is there a way to design it in a more flexible way?
2. Are my tests fine?
3. Does it do the job in the most efficient way?

Comment: Also see: [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: It's never too late for a [tag:community-challenge] ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have doubts about your unit tests — did you run them?

1. The test runner can't run your test unless it is `public`.
2. The class name `Test` collides with the `org.junit.Test` annotation.
3. For all the tests, I got `java.lang.AssertionError: Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers` — you need to specify a tolerance.

In addition, your test coverage is spotty.

4. You mentioned your concern about right-to-left associativity for the `^` operator, so why didn't you test for that?
5. Is `1 + 1 / 2` equal to 1.5 (standard precedence rules) or 1.0 (cheap calculator)?
6. Is `12 / 2 / 3` equal to 2.0 (standard associativity rules)?  **Your code evaluates it to 3.0, failing this test.**

As for the calculator itself, I think it would be worthwhile to implement support for parentheses as well.  Otherwise, there's no way to override the order of operations.

Comment: I found the bug. line 40/41 has: `result = currentOp.execute(result, calculate(equationParts[1], nextOp));` I meant `result = currentOp.execute(result, calculate(equationParts[i], nextOp));` notice the `1` and the `i`

Answer (score 5):

The nice thing about Enums is that they can be used in switch statements. Your code here:

> ```
> public double execute(double left, double right) {
>     if (this == ADD) {
>         return left + right;
>     } else if (this == SUBTRACT) {
>         return left - right;
>     } else if (this == MULTIPLY) {
>         return left * right;
>     } else if (this == DIVIDE) {
>         return left / right;
>     } else if (this == POW) {
>         return Math.pow(left, right);
>     } else {
>         // Not Possible
>         throw new InternalError();
>     }
> }
> ```

Could easily be:

```
public double execute(double left, double right) {
    switch (this) {
        case ADD:
            return left + right;
        case SUBTRACT:
            return left - right;
        case MULTIPLY:
            return left * right;
        case DIVIDE:
            return left / right;
        case POW:
            return Math.pow(left, right);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unchecked case " + this);
}
```

You could do that if you converted `Operation` to be an enum (which I recommend you do).

Note that I have changed the Error to an Exception too (with a decent message).

I would be really tempted to suggest a Java8 function though, instead. Something where you have a constructor for the Operator....

If Operator was an enum, and took a [`BinaryDoubleOperator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleBinaryOperator.html), then it could be simple...

```
public enum Operator{
    ADD('+', 1, (a,b) -> a + b),
    SUBTRACT('-', 2, (a,b) -> a - b),
    ....;

    private final DoubleBinaryOperator calculation;
    private final char symbol;
    private final int precedence;

    Operator(char symbol, int precedence, DoubleBinaryOperator calc) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.precedence = precedence;
        this.calculation = calc;
    }

    public double execute(double left, double right) {
        return calculation.applyAsDouble(left, right);
    }

    ....
}
```

Apart from that, I like the recursion, and so on. You have avoided one common bug with precedence by specifying `/` as being higher than `*`. I am not sure if that's fair though... most languages treat them the same.

Comment: Actually, you are right, `*` and `/` are supposed to be the same. The only reason that `/` is higher is that it can be calculated as a higher precedence without affecting the outcome. This also simplifies code.